# How to pair internet over usb (win10) on PiZero?

Tags: usb, windows, internet, pi-zero

I've done it before on PiZero and was working being able to ping websites.
I've reinstalled Rasberian Jessie on my SD done the same steps but now when I ping I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Should the IPv4 be as automatic or I should leave what is already in there?

My Laptop is on win10

Comment: What is "pairing" here anyway? Is Bluetooth somehow involved? There's no pairing on USB, it's plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify boot partition config.txt?
[RASPBERRY PI ZERO – PROGRAMMING OVER USB! (PART 2)](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=791)

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.